# Can I expose partial fields of a corda state to another cordapp which is in the same network?

Tags: corda

Scenario is I have two cordapps in same network. Party B of Cordapp 2 is requesting a data from Party A of Cordapp 1. So here Part A need to hide couple of fields from the state and need to expose to Party B as response.

Is it possible?

I have seen Transaction tear off, but I am not sure is it applicable here.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding but it should really only be a single cordapp that manages a particular set of states / usecases.

I think it's rare that there would be an instance that you'd want two different cordapps to be interoperable. This is an issue that should be fixed at the design.

Also remember that cordapps should be given only to the nodes you want to actually participate in specific transactions.